# Click a href button with selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, button, click, href

I have one button from one LinkedIn page with this code:

```
<div class="primary-action-button"><a class="primary-action label" href="/requestList?displayProposal=&amp;destID=39959446&amp;creationType=DC&amp;authToken=Yr4_&amp;authType=OUT_OF_NETWORK&amp;trk=vsrp_people_res_pri_act&amp;trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A2998448551382744275729%2CVSRPtargetId%3A39959446%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary">Send InMail</a></div>
```

Is there any way to click on an element just by its href link? Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using selenium you could use the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Send InMail").click()
```

Comment: I get an error: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'

Comment: fix it by using .find_element_by_link_text. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send InMail")).click();` is in Java. In python, use `find_element_by_link_text`:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Send InMail').click()
```

or something like this is sometimes helpful

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Send').click()
```